# How to solve sum of sequence range of digits with less time complexity in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, python-2.7, loops

**Sum of all digits between numbers**

Kriti has two numbers, her tution teacher give a task to her. The task is that, she wants to find the sum of all digits appearing between those two numbers.

```
For Ex:

Num1 = 8 and Num2 = 13

Output: 27

(8 + 9 + 1 + 0 + 1 + 1 + 1 + 2 + 1 +3)
```

Input Format

Input the Number1 Input the Number2

Constraints

0 <= Number1 <=1000000000

Number1 <= Number2 <=1000000000

(Negative Numbers and Decimals are not allowed)

Output Format

Display the Sum of all digits appearing between Number1 and Number2

```
Sample Input 0

8
13
Sample Output 0

27
```

MY CODE

```
a=int(input())
b=int(input())
ls=0
lst=[]
s=0

for i in range(a,b+1):
    lst.append(i)
    
for i in lst:
    if i<10:
        s=s+i
    else:
        for j in str(i):
            s=s+int(j)
print(s)
```

**This code almost clear 5/7 test cases but the problem of remaining two cases is the value of number range is 1000000000 if the input of the digits are maximum it will shows runtime error how to solve this problem efficient time with the given constrains constrains.  The problem I mentioned here was a hackerrank platform that contest was conducted by my college staff and it's finished by an hour ago**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you approach this from a digit position's perspective, you can achieve O(log10 N).

```
def sumDigits(n1,n2):
    if n2==0 or n1>n2: return 0
    p1,d1 = divmod(n1,10)        # extract last digits
    p2,d2 = divmod(n2,10)        # and prefixes
    if p1==p2:
        # same prefix: sum of last digits, digit count * sum of prefix digits
        return sum(range(d1,d2+1)) + (d2-d1+1)*sumDigits(p1,p2)
    else:
        # different prefixes: recurse lower, upper, middle ranges
        return sumDigits(p1*10+d1,p1*10+9)  \
             + sumDigits(p2*10,   p2*10+d2) \
             + sumDigits(p1+1,p2-1)*10 + (p2-p1-1)*45 # full middle range
```

For each digit position you can perform the calculation recursively by isolating the lower, middle and upper partial ranges and multiplying the sum of digits for the middle prefixes.

For example: from 1234 to 4567

- If the numbers have the same prefix before the last digits, then we only need to compute the sum of the last digits between the two numbers and recurse for the sum of digits in the prefix (which will occur once for every last digit in the range)
- Otherwise, break down the problem into lower, middle and upper ranges:

  - 1234-1239 ... 124x-455x ... 4560-4567
- The middle part will have all ending digits (0...9) for every number in the range 124x to 455x.
- So the last digit part will have a sum of 45 (∑0..9) 332 times (456-124).
- Each prefix in the middle range will be present 10 times (once for each ending digit)
- So we can compute the sum of digits for numbers in the middle range using `sumDigits(124,455) * 10 + (456-124) * 45`
- The 1234-1239 and 4560-4567 ranges can be computed by recursion (they have a common prefix by definition)

output:

```
sumDigits(8,13)                # 27
sumDigits(1234,4567)           # 52723
sumDigits(123456789,987654321) # 35514403389
```

verification:

```
sum(sum(map(int,str(n))) for n in range(8,13+1))      # 27
sum(sum(map(int,str(n))) for n in range(1234,4567+1)) # 52723

sum(sum(map(int,str(n))) for n in range(123456789,987654321+1))# takes too long
```

Answer (score 1):

Your first `for` loop is definitely useless. You should just iterate over `range(a, b + 1)` don't put it in a list - this makes interpreter hold all of the values in memory, while you only need one at any point in time, which is why you must use range. This will save whole lot of time and memory.

Other than that, there might be just a slight improvement to calculations. Here is what i'd come up with:

```
for i in range(a, b + 1):
    s += sum(map(int, str(i)))
```

Comment: Can you explain one example with the scenario of how the s+=sum(map(int,str(i))) work ??

Comment: @JanaM the `sum` returns sum of any iterable, that consists of `int`s. `map` takes 2 arguments: function and iterable. It then applies that function to each element of iterable.
So on each iteration i take current element, cast it to string to be able to iterate over it, then `map` turns this string into basically list of int that that string consists of, and finally it sums this all up and adds to `s`.

Answer (score 0):

So I guess I would do it like this:

```
a = int(input()) 
b = int(input()) 

result = 0

for i in range(a, b+1): 
    # so here we want to get the digits of i and add them up
    current_length=len(str(i)) 
    if current_length == 1:
        result+=int(i) 
    else if current_length > 1:
        for k in str(i).split(""):
            result += int(k) 

print(result)
```

I think this maybe faster than your approach, but I'm not sure, also you may need to tweak this code a bit, as I whipped it up on my phone, and could not really test it.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a list to keep track of the numbers. You just need a running sum. You can convert each number to a string. The string is iterable and allows you to find the sum of individual digits.

```
sum = 0
for i in range(a, b + 1):
    digits = str(i)
    for d in digits:
        sum += int(d)
```